# dup2 blocking printf, but not fprintf?

Tags: fork, pipe, printf, dup2

so, I have an assignment for my Operating Systems class wherein i am to create a ring of processes connected with pipes in order to pass messages between them.  i found some example code which i was looking to adapt (or at least understand) for my needs.  the example code (slightly modified) is:

```
/* Program 4.1 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Sample C program for generating a unidirectional ring of processes.Invoke this program
 with a command-line arg ument indicating the number of processes on the ring.  Communication
 is done via pipes that connect the standard output of a process to the standard input of
 its successor on the ring.  After the ring is created, each process identifies itself with
 its process ID and the  process ID of its parent.  Each process then exits. */

void main(int argc,  char *argv[ ])
{
int master_pid = getpid();
printf("master pid: %i\n", master_pid);

int   i;             /* number of this process (starting with 1)   */
int   childpid;      /* indicates process should spawn another     */
int   nprocs;        /* total number of processes in ring          */
int   fd[2];         /* file descriptors returned by pipe          */
int   error;         /* return value from dup2 call                */
/* check command line for a valid number of processes to generate */
if ( (argc != 2) || ((nprocs = atoi (argv[1])) <= 0) ) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s nprocs\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
/* connect std input to std output via a pipe */
if (pipe (fd) == -1) {
    perror("Could not create pipe");
    exit(1);
}
printf("%s\n", "test");
//this section is blocking printf()?
if ((dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) ||
    (dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)) {
    perror("Could not dup pipes");
    exit(1);
}
printf("%s\n", "test");

if ((close(fd[0]) == -1) || (close(fd[1]) == -1)) {
    perror("Could not close extra descriptors");
    exit(1);
}
/* create the remaining processes with their connecting pipes */
for (i = 1; i < nprocs;  i++) {
    if (pipe (fd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not create pipe %d: %s\n",
                i, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create child %d: %s\n",
                i, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    if (childpid > 0)        /* for parent process, reassign stdout */
        error = dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    else
        error = dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    if (error == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not dup pipes for iteration %d: %s\n",
                i, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((close(fd[0]) == -1) || (close(fd[1]) == -1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not close extra descriptors %d: %s\n",
                i, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    if (childpid)
        break;
}

/* say hello to the world */
fprintf(stderr,"This is process %d with ID %d and parent id %d\n",
        i, (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
wait(1);
exit (0);
}     /* end of main program here */
```

which outputs:

```
master pid: 30593
test
This is process 1 with ID 30593 and parent id 30286
This is process 2 with ID 30594 and parent id 30593
```

when i give is 2 as argv[1]

so, I'm wondering, why would the dup2 section prevent the printf() from executing?  if i cant even print something, i'm not sure if i could even pass the message correctly.  also, why would the fprintf() already there work, but not one that i would put there?

edit:  i would take this to my professor/TA, but theyre both out of town and will be unreachable between now and the deadline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` prints to stdout, which is file descriptor 1 (or equivalently `STDOUT_FILENO`).  [`dup2(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dup2) is duplicating the pipe's file descriptor on top of the current stdout, which has the side effect of closing the current stdout.  So, when you try to `printf` after calling that particular `dup2`, you're really printing the data into the pipe you just created, which doesn't go to your terminal output.

`fprintf(stderr, ...)` still works because that prints to stderr, not stdout, and the stderr file descriptor (2, or equivalently `STDERR_FILENO`) does not change during the program, so it continues to print out to the terminal.

Comment: wow, yeah, totally been staring at this code for WAY too long

Answer (score 0):

printf() does not send data to path 0, it sends buffered data using `stdout`. It would seem that when you disrupt path 0 by dup2'ing something to it, you're disrupting `stdout` in the process.

From the man page on dup2: `dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if  necessary`. Thus when you call `dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO)` you are breaking `stdout`.

You state that fprintf() is working but printf() is not... what path are you using for fprintf()? If you're using `stderr` then it makes perfect sense that it would continue to work, since you haven't done anything with that path.